# How could I retrieve data source from a range of time/dates on pyodbc?

Tags: date, pyodbc, date-range

I wrote 
—-cursor.execute( “SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date<= 2012-12-31 AND >= 2011-01-01”) and got “incorrect syntax near ‘>’.  As I changed to —- From_date>=‘2011-01-01’ AND To_date<=‘2012-12-31’, I got name ‘cursor’ not defined?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Just managed to solve though slow.
Fine with —
cursor.execute( “SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date>=‘2011-01-01’ AND <=‘2012-12-31’;”)
no need to put From and To, need add ‘’ for ‘date’.
* cursor no problem.  Actually might ensure with cursor=con.cursor()